# SQL - Utilizar COUNT() y CASE en simultáneo

Tags: sql

Estoy tratando de hacer el ejercicio:

[Desafío: libreta de calificaciones](https://es.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql/more-advanced-sql-queries/p/challenge-gradebook) de Khan Academy

Pero no le estoy encontrando la vuelta. Lo que tengo que hacer es agrupar por calificaciones pero sólo cuento el total.

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
    CASE
        WHEN number_grade > 90 THEN "A"
        WHEN number_grade > 80 THEN "B"
        WHEN number_grade > 70 THEN "C"
        ELSE "F"
    END AS letter_grade
FROM student_grades
ORDER BY letter_grade;
```

Y lo que obtengo son todos los datos agregados (y deberían lograr desagregarolos por calificación: A, B, C y F)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este link [Desafío: libreta de calificaciones](https://es.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql/more-advanced-sql-queries/p/challenge-gradebook) están las  otras consultas y el resto de la base de datos.

Gracias!

Comment: El link que pusiste no deja avanzar, podrías poner mejor aca algunos datos, el resultado que te arroja (que me imagino que es el de la imagen que pusiste) y el resultado que esperas

Comment: Aunque no lo dijistes, esto tiene pinta a MySQL. Cualquier otra base de datos te hubiera dado un error con esa consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución era que me equivoqué y en vez de utilizar GROUP BY, usé ORDER BY.

Respuesta Correcta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
    CASE
        WHEN number_grade > 90 THEN "A"
        WHEN number_grade > 80 THEN "B"
        WHEN number_grade > 70 THEN "C"
        ELSE "F"
    END AS letter_grade
FROM student_grades
GROUP BY letter_grade;
```